# changing the max number to -1 after every loop

Tags: java, arrays, max

I need to go over an array and find the max number and then change it to `-1`, and go over it again.

I used a `while` loop to go over the array and call function that I built to find the max number and then replace it.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

**Here is my code:**

```
public static void squarerootSort(int[] A1){
    int sqrt = (int)Math.ceil((int)Math.sqrt(A1.length));
    int []A2 = new int [sqrt];
    int index = 0;
    while(A1[FindMax(A1, 0, A1.length)] != -1){
        for (int i = 0; i <A2.length; i++) {
            A2[index++] = A1[FindMax(A1, i*sqrt,(i+1)*sqrt)];
        }
        System.out.println("The new array : " +Arrays.toString(A2));
        System.out.println("The max element is : " +A1[FindMax(A1, 0, A1.length)]);
        **A1[FindMax(A1, 0, A1.length)]=-1;**
        index =0;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem? What's wrong with the code you've already wrote? What is the input/output?

Comment: `go over it again` ...what do you do to the array after replacing the max value with `-1` ?

Comment: I need to print the max number one by one in the end.. we did a subarray in the size of is square and put there all the max in every subseq and than I need to replace the max after I find it so the next time it will print the next max ...

Comment: **A1[FindMax(A1, 0, A1.length)]=-1;**
 this line is the problem because it goes over all the big array,